# signtool selects wrong (old) certificate for code-signing

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, signtool

I have a problem which I absolutely do not understand. A few days ago I issued a new codesigning certificate from our vendor (GlobalSign).

After logging in to the build server with the user that does the build / codesigning, I started `certmgr`, navigated to the Personal certificate storage and **deleted** the old certificate. Then I used the Import dialog to import the new certificate including it's private key.

A test build showed that signtool still uses the **old** certificate to sign the application. However, I'm unable to locate this certificate anywhere in the certmgr, not even by searching for that certificates SHA1 checksum.

After some googling I found this blogpost: http://qualapps.blogspot.de/2008/07/installing-code-signing-certificate.html
It stated the following:

> Remove your old certificate. If you are renewing an existing certificate, then keeping the old certificates installed isn't usually useful, and having multiple certificates will break SIGNTOOL if signtool is searching the certificate store. Go to Control Panel / Internet Options / Content, click Certificates, select your old certificate, and click Remove. The old certificate will probably be on the Personal page if you allowed PVKIMPRT to decide where to put it.

I followed those instructions, but the only thing I can find is the new certificate.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool" sign /v /sm /n "my company name" /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com "the-setup.exe"
```

"my company name" is the name that is contained in both the old and the new certificate.

a. How can I find out where the old certificate is still stored and delete it?
b. How can I force signtool to use the new certificate, or at least fail?!

Comment: I worked around this problem by using a .pfx file directly instead of the certificate storage, like described in a  blogpost I read: `signtool.exe sign /f codesign.pfx /p PASSWORD -tr "http://www.startssl.com/timestamp" "Hello World.exe"`

Found here: https://www.pierschel.com/de/software-blog/18-code-signing-tutorial-de

Answer (score 2):

The workaround with using the PFX file and referencing to it is a good solution.

However, you may try the following:

- add the parameter `/s MY` to the signtool parameters chain. "MY" links to the Personal store.
- in certmgr.msc, look in other stores, if they do not contain a copy of the old certificate
- add `/a` to the parameters chain. This will cause to "automatically select the best signing certificate" (whatever this means :))
- you may wait until the old certificate expires. After that, it should automatically use only the new certificate

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will, however, stick with my workaround for now, because:
a.) The certificate has expired by now, and I can't easily test your solution reliably
b.) I already searched all the stores in certmgr multiple times and couldn't find the old certificate
c.) The "workaround" seems somewhat clearer to me than adding even more "mystic" `/a` parameters ;)

Answer (score 1):

My situation seems similar, though in my case, putting the password for the certificate file in my build script wasn't an option. I was having trouble using any MMC snap-in to view (such as certmgr.msc) to view the certificate stores because Windows Server 2012 R2 wasn't allowing my non-admin build user to use the snap-ins. I resorted to trying a variation of a PowerShell script that I found here (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7ed48943-22e2-4afd-aa77-2424d2a9eee1/how-to-delete-archived-certificates-using-the-certutil-command?forum=winserversecurity):

```
$store = New-Object  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store "My","CurrentUser"

$MaxAllowedIncludeArchive = ([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.openflags]::MaxAllowed –bor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.openflags]::IncludeArchived)
$store.Open($MaxAllowedIncludeArchive)

[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection] $certificates = $store.certificates

foreach ($cert in $certificates)
{
  Write-Host $cert
}

$store.Close()
```

It showed me the certificate that was creating the conflict for me. (Strangely, trying to use `certutil -viewstore My` yielded a different set of certificates. (The placement of certificate stores is still unfortunately confusing to me.)

In my case, the problem was that I wanted a newer SHA256 certificate instead of my older SHA1 certificate so adding an appropriate /i argument to my signtool command (with the SHA256 issuer name) fixed my problem.